# Tidying dataset to create graphs in R of dataset with multiple variables and multiple entries per variable

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have a dataset (made a fake one here), that I need to make a graph out of. The issue is that there are multiple IDs, and each ID has multiple x and y values at different time points. I want to be able to plot all these in the same graph, however, there are more than 400 IDs, each with two variables. I have made an example code to show a similar structure

```
ID <- c(1, 2, 3)
age1 <- c(10, 15, 20)
age2 <- c(11, 16, 21)
age3 <- c(12, 17, 22)
weight1 <- c(30, 50, 60)
weight2 <- c(35, 55, 65)
weight3 <- c(38, 56, 67)
df <- data.frame(ID, age1, age2, age3, weight1, weight2, weight3)
```

I want it to be like this

[image: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08aIY.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08aIY.png)]

I cant simply delete duplicates as many numbers are duplicates

I have tried

```
df_new <- df %>%
                       gather(age,
                              age_value,
                              age1:age3
                             )%>%
                       gather(weight,
                              weight_value,
                              weight1:weight3
                             )
```

However this gives me multiple duplicates of Y.

I am currently at a loss on how to solve this issue.

this results in
[image]

Comment: Please provide test data as the output from `dput()`. Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/).

Comment: your sample dataset doesn't match the screenshot!

Comment: Ah I am sorry, I had changed it, however I didnt notice this. Thank you! I will update!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want this:

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(df, -ID, names_to = c(".value", "time"), names_pattern = "(\\w+)(\\d+)")
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 9 × 4
     ID time    age weight
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 1        10     30
2     1 2        11     35
3     1 3        12     38
4     2 1        15     50
5     2 2        16     55
6     2 3        17     56
7     3 1        20     60
8     3 2        21     65
9     3 3        22     67
```

Note:

The `names_pattern` is a regular expression, looking for a group of words, then a digit. The digit goes into the `time` column, whereas the word tells us the column the value should go into, either the `age` or the `weight` column.

Comment: note: if you wanted to do this with gather, in a way which might be more familiar to you, you could do something like this:

Comment: `ages <- df |>
    gather(age,
            age_value,
            age1:age3)  |>
    select(-starts_with("weight")) |>
    mutate(age = parse_number(age))`

Comment: `weights <- df |> gather(weight, weight_value, weight1:weight3)  |> select(-starts_with("age")) |> mutate(weight = parse_number(weight))`

Comment: then join: `left_join(ages, weights, by = c("ID", "age" = "weight")) `

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't fully understand the names_pattern part as of yet, however, I will read the explanation first before I ask further questions! I really appreciate it!

Comment: no worries! :-) regular expressions are just fancy text matching things. They look quite intimidating but they're very handy when you're in a pinch

Comment: I just wanted to let you know, that you are my hero! I used chatgpt to further explain what the names_pattern was and it worked like a charm! Thank you! Now I am thinking about how to best remove NA

Comment: no worries, glad I could help! :-)

Comment: what NAs are you talking about?